# EF Data annotations Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I need regular expression validation for first 5 digits are numbers then hyphen and then one digit is alphabet and other one is numeric.

ex : 23456-p5 or 12345-a3 something like that.

I have tried something like this to start with

```
/^\d{5}-\d{2}$/
```

and in model i have given like this as we don't have to give ^ or $ in data annotations

```
[RegularExpression(@"d{5}-\d{2}")]
```

But i couldnt get it to work even this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}-[a-zA-Z]\d$")]
```

Answer (score 1):

An expression like this should work:

```
^\d{5}\-[A-Za-z]\d$
```